How to generate a bootstrap standard error, t statistics and p value for a user written dynamic panel quantile regression
rm(list=ls())
library(quantreg)
library(SparseM)
library(stats)

rq.fit.panel <- function(X,y,s,w=c(1),taus=0.30,lambda = 0){
  # prototype function for panel data fitting of QR models
  # the matrix X is assumed to contain an intercept
  # the vector s is a strata indicator assumed (so far) to be a one-way layout
  # NB:  
  # 1.  The value of the shrinkage parameter lambda is an open research problem in
  #     the simplest homogneous settings it should be the ratio of the scale parameters
  #     of the fixed effects and the idiocyncratic errors
  # 2.  On return the coefficient vector has m*p + n elements where m is the number
  # quantiles being estimated, p is the number of colums of X, and n is the
  # number of distinct values of s.  The first m*p coefficients are the 
  # slope estimates, and the last n are the "fixed effects"
  # 3.  Like all shrinkage (regularization) estimators, asymptotic inference is somewhat
  # problematic... so the bootstrap is the natural first resort.
  
  
  require(SparseM)
  require(quantreg)
  K <- length(w)
  if(K != length(taus))
    stop("length of w and taus must match")
  X <- as.matrix(X)
  p <- ncol(X)
  n <- length(levels(as.factor(s)))
  N <- length(y)
  if(N != length(s) || N != nrow(X))
    stop("dimensions of y,X,s must match")
  Z <- as.matrix.csr(model.matrix(~as.factor(s)-1))
  Fidelity <- cbind(as(w,"matrix.diag.csr") %x% X,w %x% Z)
  Penalty <- cbind(as.matrix.csr(0,n,K*p),lambda*as(n,"matrix.diag.csr"))
  D <- rbind(Fidelity,Penalty)
  y <- c(w %x% y,rep(0,n))
  a <- c((w*(1-taus)) %x% (t(X)%*%rep(1,N)),
         sum(w*(1-taus)) * (t(Z) %*% rep(1,N)) + lambda * rep(1,n))
  rq.fit.sfn(D,y,rhs=a)
}


norm<-function(x)(
  sqrt(sum(x^2))
)


"tsls" <-
  function(x1, x2, z, y, int = T)
  {
    # two stage least squares
    if(int){
      
      x2<- cbind(x2)
      z <- cbind(x1, z)
    }
    x2hat <- lm(x2~z)$fitted.values
    xhat <-cbind(x1,x2hat)
    R <- lm(y ~ xhat)
    return(R)
  }



#This function computes matrices of means and deviations from means 
#used by the panel2 function. 
# Input: x = a matrix data indexed by id 
#       id = a factor variable indexing x 
# Output: list containing: xm<-matrix of means 
#                          xdm<-matrix of deviations from means. 
panmat<-function(x,id) 
{ 
  x<-as.matrix(x) 
  id<-as.factor(id) 
  xm<- apply(x,2,function(y,z) tapply(y,z, mean), z=id) 
  xdm<- x-apply(xm, 2, function(y,z) rep(y,table(z)),z=id) 
  list(xm=xm, xdm=xdm) 
} 


########
#INPUTS
############ DATA DECLARATION

set.seed(123)  # For reproducibility

t <- 10  # Number of time periods
n <- 5  # Number of individuals

# Create individual and time indices
individuals <- rep(1:n, each=t)
time <- rep(1:t, times=n)

# Generate random data
y <- rnorm(n*t)  # Dependent variable
y.lag1 <- c(NA, y[-length(y)])  # Lagged dependent variable
y.lag1[time == 1] <- NA  # No lag for the first period of each individual
x1 <- rnorm(n*t)# Exogenous variable
X2<- rnorm(n*t)
X3<- rnorm(n*t)
iv <- rnorm(n*t)  # Instrument variable

# Combine into a data frame
data <- data.frame(individuals, time, y, y.lag1, x1, X2, X3, iv)
data <- na.omit(data)  # Remove NA rows caused by lagged variable

# Prepare the input variables
Y.lag_IV <- cbind(data$iv, data$x1, data$X2, data$X3)  # Instrument and control variables
s <- data$individuals  # Individual identifiers

# Ensure the dependent and lagged dependent variables are aligned correctly
y <- data$y
y.lag1 <- data$y.lag1




AA<-seq(0.10,0.90,0.10)


estimate_coefficeints <- function(AA, Y.lag_IV,y ,y.lag1, s)
{ 
  betas <- numeric(lenght(AA))
  for(k in seq_along(AA)) {
    fit<- rq.fit.panel(Y.lag_IV,(y-AA[k]*y.lag1),s)
    
    betas[k]<- fit$coef[1]
    
    fixed_effect_coefs<- fit$coef[-1]
    if (length(fixed_effect_coefs)
        >0) {
      betas <- c(betas, fixed_effect_coefs)
    }
  }
  return(betas)
}


betas<-array(NA, dim=c(length(AA),1))
g<-array(NA, dim=c(length(AA),1))

for (k in 1:length(AA))
  betas[k]<-rq.fit.panel(Y.lag_IV,(y-AA[k]*y.lag1),s)$coef[1]
end

for (k in 1:length(AA))
  g[k]<-norm(betas[k])

end

I<-which.min(g)
param1<-AA[I]

#plot(AA,g)

autoreg.tslsqr<-param1
final.reg<-rq.fit.panel(Y.lag_IV,(y-param1*y.lag1),s)
slope.tslsqr<-final.reg$coef[2]
coefs<-c(param1,final.reg$coef[-1])


# Display the final coefficients
coefs

NB: The code above is an R code that estimates dynamic quantile panel regression with IV. I have used an hypothetical data to run the code. However, the output of the code only shows the coefficient. No standard error, no t statistics and p values. I have been trying to bootstrap the standard error, t statistics and p values but it hasn't been successful. I want someone to help me with this so I can be able to make meaningful inference from the output.
I am a little bit new to R, so I haven't really tried much on it.
